# converting a time stamp from microseconds past midnight using awk

Tags: awk

I have a large linux file that prints out a timestamp on each line, marked as microseconds past midnight.  I've been trying to come up with a clever short awk script that will change it into a YY-mm-d HH:MM:SS.ms format using awk (I have checked some other posts on here, but most deal with converting from the epoch and not since midnight today).  I've tried a few things with strftime, but nothing that seems to be getting me the correct date and time.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you define 'midnight' here? I assume they are different days' midnight. Correct?
If so, it is more of a question for converting into HH:MM:SS.ms? And sample input and expected result would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume by "microseconds since midnight" you mean an integral number of microseconds

```
echo 86399123456 | awk '
    BEGIN { midnight = mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d 0 0 0", systime())) }
    {
        seconds = $1 / 1e6
        fraction = $1 % 1e6
        printf "%s.%06d\n", strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T", midnight + seconds), fraction
    }
'
```

outputs

```
2013-01-23 23:59:59.123456
```